# Repeat each date specific number of times

Tags: date, count, insert

I have gotten so much help form this forum from times to times, but this is the first time I am posting a question.
What I need is:

I have an excel file that is extracted from a machine, which records temperatures every 15 minutes per hour, 24 hours per day, every day per month... (96 rows per day)

In Column A we have the dates

```
01/09/2017 (x96 times)

02/09/2017 (x96 times)

...

...

...

30/09/2017 (x96 times)
```

Sometimes this machine gets stuck and stops recording, so until it gets back to work and start recording again, I have already missed some records, which I have to enter by hand.

So, I need a macro, to check if each date of the month has 96 rows in column A and if not then add the missing rows... It happens some dates to have 70 rows, so in that case I need the macro to insert another 26 rows of the same date...

I don't know if this is easy, but it would be very helpful if someone could give me a solution.

Comment: Please edit your question properly. Remove unnecessary details

Comment: You shouldn't expect someone to develop a piece of code for you on SO. Please explore your own solution and if you meet some problem with it, ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi, I have already made my own searching but I couldn't come to a solution...that's why I posted here...If I wrote too many information, I am sorry, but I was trying to be explanative...